# jGit rev-parse with groovy

Tags: groovy, jgit

I'm trying to get the same value from rev-parse but using jGit library and Groovy script. I Found in documentation jGit that [Link](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.html), but it is straight from Java, how to rebuild code for groovy ? 
Thanks for tips !

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.eclipse.jgit', module='org.eclipse.jgit', version='4.8.0.201706111038-r')
)


import org.eclipse.jgit.api.*;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.*;
import java.io.IOException;

class RevCommit {
  static void main(String[] args) {
      Git git = Git.open( new File( ".git" ) );
      ObjectId head = git.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
      Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().add(head).setMaxCount(1).call();

   }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample you have shown searches for last commit. If you want to achieve same thing using Groovy script you have to put body of this Java `main` method directly to Groovy script - it does not need any class with `main` method to be executed. You also have to fix `git.resolve(Constants.HEAD)` - you are trying to call a method that does not exist. This method exists in [`Repository`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) class.

Below you can find an example of Groovy script that does similar things to the Java example:

```
@Grab(group='org.eclipse.jgit', module='org.eclipse.jgit', version='4.8.0.201706111038-r')

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.*
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit

Git git = Git.open(new File("."))
ObjectId head = git.repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD)
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().add(head).setMaxCount(1).call()

println "Recent commit:"
commits.each {
    println it.toString()
}
```

I saved this script to the file called `jgit.groovy` and run with following command:

```
groovy jgit.groovy
```

The output for this script is similar to:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Recent commit:
commit 8504bf656a945fe199bea60fd1296eef2b083a18 1500237139 ----sp
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDoe Cool, I'm glad I could help you. Good luck!